# register data from csv file to mnesia database

Tags: csv, erlang

I want to store data from a csv file in an mnesia database (specifically in the table named "**user**")

I find in this forum this kind of solution :

Create fie named **csv.erl** :

```
%%% --- csv parser in Erlang. ------
%%% To help process large csv files without loading them into
%%% memory. Similar to the xml parsing technique of SAX

-module(csv).
-compile(export_all).

parse(FilePath,ForEachLine,Opaque)->
    case file:open(FilePath,[read]) of
        {_,S} ->
            start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,Opaque);
        Error -> Error
    end.

start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,Opaque)->
    Line = io:get_line(S,''),
    case Line of
        eof -> {ok,Opaque};
        "\n" -> start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,Opaque);
        "\r\n" -> start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,Opaque);
        _ -> 
            NewOpaque = ForEachLine(scanner(clean(clean(Line,10),13)),Opaque),
            start_parsing(S,ForEachLine,NewOpaque)
    end.

scan(InitString,Char,[Head|Buffer]) when Head == Char -> 
    {lists:reverse(InitString),Buffer};
scan(InitString,Char,[Head|Buffer]) when Head =/= Char ->
    scan([Head|InitString],Char,Buffer);
scan(X,_,Buffer) when Buffer == [] -> {done,lists:reverse(X)}.
scanner(Text)-> lists:reverse(traverse_text(Text,[])).

traverse_text(Text,Buff)->
    case scan("",$,,Text) of
        {done,SomeText}-> [SomeText|Buff];
        {Value,Rem}-> traverse_text(Rem,[Value|Buff])
    end.

clean(Text,Char)-> 
    string:strip(string:strip(Text,right,Char),left,Char).
```

create function **test :**

```
test()->

    ForEachLine = fun(Line,Buffer)-> io:format("Line: ~p~n",[Line]),Buffer end,

 InitialBuffer = [],

 csv:parse("/home/include/user.csv",ForEachLine,InitialBuffer).
```

But this solution displays just the data in the Erlang console (it displays each line from the csv file) but my goal is to store these lines from csv file in the user table.

I have already create a record of user

```
-record(user, {id, firstname, lastname, birthday}).
```

to register the line from csv file to **user** table  I try with

```
test()->

    ForEachLine = fun(Line,Buffer)-> io:format("Line: ~p~n",[Line]),Buffer end,

 InitialBuffer = [],

 csv:parse("/home/test/user.csv",ForEachLine,InitialBuffer),



   F = fun() ->
         Line=#user{},
         mnesia:write(Line),                               
         {ok}

     end,
     {atomic, Val} = mnesia:transaction(F),
     Val.
```

but this function does not insert data in the user table

Comment: The `delimiter` may change across different `.csv` files. Look at the answer edit to see how you can customise the `.csv parser` to cater for any `delimiter`. In the parser, i assumed a `comma`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a couple of things:

- Create a schema in mnesia which will hold your data. That is create a `#user{}` record.
- Take your line and make it into a record of type `R = #user{}`
- Call `mnesia:write(R)` inside a transaction. To make it faster you can batch a couple of writes inside the same transaction or simply use `mnesia:dirty_write(R)`.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of this module. Now, the Functional Object which you have passed to the library to apply onto every Line it finds, you can customise it to your liking. For example:

```
F = fun(Line,_) -> 
        [Id,Firstname, Lastname, Birthday] = Line,
        U = #user{
            id = Id,
            firstname = Firstname,
            lastname = Lastname,
            birthday = Birthday
        },
        mnesia:dirty_write(U),
        []
    end.
```

Now, remember that, if the file is formatted very well as `.csv` , which will mean that every line is the same as the next line, then a pattern match will be okay as i have done in the `Fun` above. Normally, the headings (the first line in a `.csv` file) will show the columns in the whole data set so that the preceeding lines can use the first one as a template.

Putting that aside, Look at the line, and then transform that `Line` into an erlang record. You can use the `Buffer` variable as a counter, because it is subsequently updated by each `Fun` call. Remember that the `Fun` exits with the updated `Buffer` variable, so that it can apply it to the next Line in the `.csv` file. Hence, if you understand your `recursion` very well, your Buffer variable can be an Integer, starting from `Zero` and then you increment it at the end of each `Fun` call. Here is an example:

```
F = fun(Line,Counter) -> 
        [Id,Firstname, Lastname, Birthday] = Line,
        U = #user{
            id = Id,
            firstname = Firstname,
            lastname = Lastname,
            birthday = Birthday
        },
        mnesia:dirty_write(U),
        Counter + 1
    end.
```

In the example above, your `Buffer` is now just a counter. This will automatically show you the total number of records inserted into mnesia from the `.csv` file.

Please remember how generic erlang data structure are. Your `Fun`, as long as it is constructed to take two variables, the first one being the Line, you can customise it to be anything. Inside the `Fun` , you can even be sending the `Line` to another erlang node, or erlang process. Like this:

```
F = fun(Line,Server)-> 
        [Id,Firstname, Lastname, Birthday] = Line,
        U = #user{
            id = Id,
            firstname = Firstname,
            lastname = Lastname,
            birthday = Birthday
        },
        Server ! {from_csv,U}
        Server
    end.
```

In the example above, your `Buffer` variable is a constant, which is the `Pid` or `Registered Name` of a process to which you will send every record from the `.csv` file. In conclusion, the Buffer variable may or maynot be updated in every subsequent `Fun` call onto the next line, depends on you. You may just be passing the same constant variable (Some tuple, or atom or Pid, or String, whatever, as long as you know what it is and you might make use of it in your program) at the end of the `Fun`. Then , each `Line` must be pattern matched and then transformed into the appropriate `Mnesia record`.

---

**Major Answer EDIT**
 Now, in the library module, i assumed that the `delimiter` for your `.csv` file is a `comma`. In that module, i want you to look at the function: `traverse_text/2`, it currently looks like this:

```
traverse_text(Text,Buff)->
    case scan("",$,,Text) of
        {done,SomeText}-> [SomeText|Buff];
        {Value,Rem}-> traverse_text(Rem,[Value|Buff])
    end.
```

PLEASE CHANGE THAT FUNCTION ABOVE IN ORDER TO REFLECT YOUR `DELIMITER`. Forexample, if the `delimiter` is a `semi-colon ( ; )`, then, that function changes to:

```
traverse_text(Text,Buff)->
    case scan("",$;,Text) of
        {done,SomeText}-> [SomeText|Buff];
        {Value,Rem}-> traverse_text(Rem,[Value|Buff])
    end.
```

Hence, in case you `delimiter` is different, just make the change in that function as i have showed above ( i hope you see where the symbol goes, where you see the `dollar sign, followed by your actual delimiter` ). Then, recompile and re-load that module. Let me know in case you run into more challenges.